# Java with Eclipse: JDK Compliance configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, version, backwards-compatibility

In `Java` | `Compiler` preferences there are 3 levels of Java to be set (in Kepler):

- `Compiler compliance level`
- `Generated .class files compatibility`
- `Source compatibility`

The two latter can be set manually or defaulted to value derived from `Compiler compliance level`.

**Question 1**

*What is `Compiler compliance level` used for?*

- It seems we already have source and binary compliance settings with other parameters...
  Here [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/ref-preferences-compiler.htm) doesn't really help. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987559/eclipse-java-source-compatibility-vs-compiler-compliance-level), and [the linked web page](http://eclipseandjazz.blogspot.in/2011/11/of-compliance-and-source-settings-in.html), are quite difficult to understand.
- It seems this is related to the javac compiler, not the Eclipse integrated compiler. Is it correct?

**Question 2**

*Why Eclipse in many cases requires `Compiler compliance` >= `.class files` >= `Source`*

- For instance levels 1.7 (compiler), 1.4 (.class), and 1.7 (source) is not allowed. Why?
- I was expecting to be possible to write source at 1.7 standard with all latest features, and compile for 1.4 VM (translating new language features into 1.4 compatible byte-code)
- Eclipse allows `Compiler compliance` 1.4, `.class` 1.2, and `Source` 1.3 (as depicted in the help page mentioned above, and actually checked). Why?

**Question 3**

- I hope I'll be able to answer myself after reading explanations provided: *I've JDK 7 installed, I want to compile classes runnable with JRE 1.4, preferably using features like geerics. Which levels are required for the 3 settings?*

I would appreciate any clarification or links to appropriate documentation.